# BigQuery ARRAY_AGG with batches

Tags: sql, arrays, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

Is there are some simple method to aggregate values into batches (with saving order)

from this

```
key | value
----+------
a   |  1
a   |  2
a   |  3
a   |  4
a   |  5
a   |  6

b   |  9
b   |  8
b   |  7
b   |  6
b   |  5
b   |  4
```

to this

```
key | batches
----+-------------------------------------------------------------
a   | [{'values': [1, 2]}, {'values': [3, 4]}, {'values': [5, 6]}]
b   | [{'values': [9, 8]}, {'values': [7, 6]}, {'values': [5, 4]}]
```

`{'values': [1, 2]}` - STRUCT
`[{'values': [1, 2]}, {'values': [3, 4]}, {'values': [5, 6]}]` - REPEATED   STRUCTs

Answer (score 2):

For BigQuery Standard SQL

> Is there are some simple method to aggregate values into batches (**with saving order**)

Note; in order to "save order" - you need to have some indication of this order in your data - I assume you have something that define that order (I use `ts` field for this) - usually it is a timestamp or order/position type of data, etc.

So, below is starting point to achieve exactly above goal

```
#standardSQL
SELECT key, 
  ARRAY_AGG(value ORDER BY pos) AS batch,
  DIV(pos - 1, 2) batch_num
FROM (
  SELECT *, 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY key ORDER BY ts) pos,
    DIV(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY key ORDER BY ts) - 1, 2) batch
  FROM `project.dataset.table`
)
GROUP BY key, batch_num
```

If to apply to sample data from your question - output is

[image]

From here, you can package above result into whatever final format you need - for example

```
#standardSQL
SELECT key, ARRAY_AGG(batch ORDER BY batch_num) batches
FROM (
  SELECT key, 
    STRUCT(ARRAY_AGG(value ORDER BY pos) AS values) batch,
    DIV(pos - 1, 2) batch_num
  FROM (
    SELECT *, 
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY key ORDER BY ts) pos,
      DIV(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY key ORDER BY ts) - 1, 2) batch
    FROM `project.dataset.table`
  )
  GROUP BY key, batch_num
)
GROUP BY key
```

which give below output (quite close to expected example in your question)

```
[
  {
    "key": "a",
    "batches": [
      {
        "values": [
          "1",
          "2"
        ]
      },
      {
        "values": [
          "3",
          "4"
        ]
      },
      {
        "values": [
          "5",
          "6"
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "key": "b",
    "batches": [
      {
        "values": [
          "9",
          "8"
        ]
      },
      {
        "values": [
          "7",
          "6"
        ]
      },
      {
        "values": [
          "5",
          "4"
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: but `OVER(PARTITION BY key ORDER BY True)` 
does not guarantee order?

Comment: I don't see `ORDER BY True` anywhere in my answer! please clarify your comment - and also read again note on top of my answer :o)

Comment: sorry. I meant that I want to replace `OVER(PARTITION BY key ORDER BY ts)` with `OVER(PARTITION BY key ORDER BY True)` if there are no something like timestamp in source table.

Comment: If you don't have any field that you can use as an indication of order - it means that there is no any order in your data and thus unfortunately nothing to preserve  - so you can just remove order by to part - so you still will get batches but no order will be guaranteed